# Rails / Carrierwave / GIT / nginx / Capistrano - can't create a directory in git releases folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, capistrano, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave in a rails app to upload files. It works fine on my development environment, but on my production VM (Ubuntu), I'm getting this error:

An Errno::EACCES occurred in users#update:

```
  Permission denied - /home/yards/apps/yardsapp/releases/20130616143623/public/uploads/tmp/20130616-1438-14186-3184
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:244:in `mkdir'
```

I'm pretty sure I understand what is going on, but I can't seem to figure out a fix. My capistrano deploy.rb is set up with the user as root. So when it creates the new release folder on a deploy, the access rights are for root (I think).

Then when I try to upload a file, I get that error because nginx is trying to execute a mkdir as www-data.

I could chown the folder after the deploy and it works...but then another deploy creates another new directory with owner set to root as default.

At least I think this is what is going on. Does anyone have any ideas on how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your deployment as `www-data`. You might need to adjust the `authorized_keys` file for the `www-data` user as well to be able to connect.

To fastest way would be to copy over your `authorized_keys` file for whatever user you are using at the moment (assuming you are root):

```
mkdir $WWW_DATA_HOME/.ssh
cp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys $WWW_DATA_HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown www-data:www-data $WWW_DATA_HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You might also need to change the shell for the `www-data` user to log in to it:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash www-data
```

Now you should be able to do

```
ssh www-data@your-host.tld
```

and log in.

Comment: I think you're right here. However, I'm not quite sure how to adjust my authorized_keys file. Any insight on that? Its trying to deploy as www-data and asking me for a password (I don't think there is a password for www-data?)

Comment: added some information on it - in essence, you need to ssh into the server, and change the things with another account. Afterwards, you'll be able to log in as `www-data`.

Answer (score 0):

What this came down to was an improper Capistrano configuration. I followed the capistrano docs correctly (and made a 'deployer' user, same thing as the www-data as suggested above) and I have capistrano working like a charm. Also upgraded to Capistrano 3.